# XML data to html by php

Tags: php, html, xml

i'm trying to convert the content in XML in HTML to show that on browser, i had found online converter, here is the link https://codebeautify.org/xml-to-html-converter what it do is, basically it takes the XML data and gives the html output, as the image shown below

[image]

but i want to do this in PHP, i had searched about this in google but didn't found related solutions.

here below is what i tried

```
<?php

$file = 'https://demo.conitor.in/Remembered/views/feed.php';

if(!$xml = simplexml_load_file($file)){
    echo "file not found!";
} else {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($xml);
    echo "</pre>";    
}

?>
```

and here is my xml data URL:- https://demo.conitor.in/Remembered/views/feed.php

Comment: Hi, this is not a code writing service (there's no way for you to pay us for our work!), and there isn't really enough code here for us to fix a specific problem for you. If you haven't already, please check the [tour] and the [help] for how to get the most out of this site.

Comment: hi @IMSoP thank you for your suggestion, i'm not asking for written code i can manage that, i was asking about any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[simplexml_load_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) will convert the well-formed XML document in the given file to an object.

And you can iterate through the object as follows.

```
<?php

$file = 'https://demo.conitor.in/Remembered/views/feed.php';

if(!$xml = simplexml_load_file($file)){
    // Will return false if the file doesn't contain a well formated XML document.
    echo "file not found!";
} else {
    echo "<table><thead><tr><th>Number</th><th>Title</th><th>First Name</th><th>State</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
    $i = 0;

    // Refere your SimpleXmlObject Struture for more information.
    foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {


       echo "<tr><td>" .++$i ."</td><td>" . $item->title . "</td><td>" . $item->DeceasedFirstName . "</td><td>" . $item->State ."</td></tr>";


    }


    echo "</tbody></table>";
}
?>
```